# window.alert is not a function and alert is no defined JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

So I tried running

```
alert("test");
```

and I tried

```
window.alert("test");
```

I tried them both in jsconsole.com and I also tried running them in a remote js script via script src. None of those methods worked. But for some reason they work perfectly within  tags without src.

I tried this in Chrome, Firefox, and the default android browser. (I am coding on mobile)

What's going on here stackoverflow? This is strange...

Comment: because jsconsole.com doesn't want to run that particular function on their platform. You can run it on your own website though

Comment: I tried running it on an html file on my server and that did not work.

Comment: Show how you did it. Provide the code for that section

Comment: <script src="http://0.0.0.0:8080/test.js"></script> simply with alert("test"); or window.alert("test");

Comment: I was using eval to do this.

Answer (score -2):

I fixed it. I don't know how but it works now :/

Thanks anyways